# Writing a comparison BATCH file to verify sha256sum to released code

Tags: bash, debugging, curl, jq, url-parameters

Trying to write a script that takes 2 arguments ($1 and $2) one to represent the $hash and the $file_name.

I am trying to utilize `jq` to parse the required data to download and compare PASS or FAIL.

I see to be stuck trying to think this out.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#
# Sifchain shasum check (revised).
#

# $1
hash_url=$( curl -R -s https://api.github.com/repos/Sifchain/sifnode/releases | jq '.[] | select(.name=="v0.10.0-rc.4")' | jq '.assets[]' | jq 'select(.name=="sifnoded-v0.10.0-rc.4-linux-amd64.zip.sha256")' | jq '.browser_download_url' | xargs $1 $2 )
echo $hash_url
# $2
hash=$( curl -s -L $hash_url | jq'.$2')

file_name=$(curl -R -s https://api.github.com/repos/Sifchain/sifnode/releases | jq '.[] | .name')



#
#
echo $hash | sha256sum
echo $file_name | sha256sum #null why?
echo "\n"
## version of the release $1,     and the hash $2
## sha256 <expected_sha_256_sum> <name_of_the_file>
sha256() {
  if echo "$1  $2" #| sha256sum -c --quiet
  then
    echo pass $1 $2
    exit 0
  else
    echo FAIL $1 $2
    exit 1
  fi
}

# Invoke sha256
sha256 $hash_url $file_name
```

Ideally this should work for any comparison of hash with correct file, pulling the 2 parameters when the BASH script is invoked.

Comment: `jq'.$2'` doesn't look correct to me. Do you mean `jq ".$2"` ?

Comment: I think your are right, single quotes and double quotes always throw me.

Comment: `curl -R -s https://api.github.com/repos/Sifchain/sifnode/releases | jq '.[] | .name'` returns multiple names.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following corrections/modifications:

```
#!/bin/bash

#sha file

SHA_URL=$(curl -R -s https://api.github.com/repos/Sifchain/sifnode/releases | \
            jq --arg VERSION v0.10.0-rc.4 -r \
                '.[] | select(.name==$VERSION) | .assets[] | select(.name |test("\\.sha256$")) | .browser_download_url')

SHA_VALUE=$(curl -s -L $SHA_URL| tr 1 2)

FILENAME=$(curl -R -s https://api.github.com/repos/Sifchain/sifnode/releases | \
             jq --arg VERSION v0.10.0-rc.4 -r \
                 '.[] | select(.name==$VERSION) | .assets[]  | select(.content_type =="application/zip") | .name')

#added just for testing, I'm assuming you have the files locally allready
FILEURL=$(curl -R -s https://api.github.com/repos/Sifchain/sifnode/releases | \
             jq --arg VERSION v0.10.0-rc.4 -r \
                 '.[] | select(.name==$VERSION) | .assets[]  | select(.content_type =="application/zip") | .browser_download_url')

wget --quiet $FILEURL -O $FILENAME

echo $SHA_VALUE $FILENAME | sha256sum -c --quiet >/dev/null 2>&1
RESULT=$?
if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -n "PASS "
else
    echo -n "FAIL "
fi

echo $SHA_VALUE $FILENAME
exit $RESULT
```

Notes:

- jq

  - `--arg VERSION v0.10.0-rc.4` creates a "variable" to be used in the script
  - `-r` - raw output, strings are not quoted
  - `test("\\.sha256$")` - regular expresion, used to search for a generic sha256, so you don't have to hardcode the full name
  - `select(.content_type =="application/zip")` - I'm assuming that's the file you are searching for
- wget is used just for demo purpose, to download the file, I'm assuming you already have the file on your machine
- `sha256sum -c --quiet >/dev/null 2>&1` - redirecting to /dev/null is necessary because in case of error sha256sum is not quiet

Comment: Thanks, @Sorin this really helps me out.